# I got some errors when install single node mode

Tags: cloud-foundry

log:

```
error : gnutls_handshake() failed : a TLS packet with unexpected length was received .
while accessing https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/info/refs
fatal: http request failed
.. unable to clone cloudfoundry vcap repo
```

What can I do?

Thanks tt64

Comment: My vm is ubuntu server 10.4.04

Comment: I would suggest that you try the vcap dev website for these types of questions ( https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev )

Answer (score 1):

are you behind a firewall? Are you using vcap dev_setup to install your CF instance? If you are make sure you are not behind any sort of firewalls that would block your execution from grabbing anything it needs from the net.